# How do I make a column a link in datatables.js?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to figure out how to make a column a link in dataTables.js.  I have it mostly working but can't get the link to appear.

```
var dataSet = [
 ['PR12345','Test O Rama','5/7/2015','Open'],
 ['PRJ_AR09','Project Name','5/8/2015','New Request'],
 ['PRJ_AR18','Test Project','5/10/2015','New Request'],
 ['PR092134','Test Project 1','5/10/2015','Open'],
 ['PRO012333','Test Project 2','5/10/2015','Open'],
 ['PRO83880','Test Project 3','5/10/2015','Open']
];
$(function() {
    $('#demo').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="workQueueTable"></table>' );
    $('#workQueueTable').DataTable({
    "data": dataSet,
    "columns": [
        { "title": "Project ID", "sWidth": "10%", "fnRender": function(data) {
                return "<a href='" + data + "'></a>";
                }  },
        { "title": "Project Name" },
        { "title": "Date Requested", "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "title": "Status", "sWidth": "15%" }
    ]
    });
});
```

[Example Code](http://codepen.io/jd80104/pen/rVwRQM?editors=101)

Can't seem to get the link to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found the answer.  fnRender has been depreciated so you must use mRender now.

Amazing how everything just works better when you use the correct syntax.

Comment: You also have to include the text: ``return "<a href='" + data + "'>" + data + "</a>";`` You where posting empty anchors.

Comment: Since you're using DataTables 1.10, the correct option is [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render). Although `mRender ` is still backward supported, it's recommended to use newer option names.